# Leer fragmentos de código

Tags: java, mvc, condiciones, controller, código-fuente

Acudo a su ayuda para leer estos fragmentos de código:

**

> *DefaultTableModel modT = new DefaultTableModel();***

---

> if (e.getSource() == frm.btnGuardar) {**

*

**

> *if (modDAO.registrar(mod)) {
>                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro guardado con éxito");
>                   limpiar();
>                   modT.setRowCount(0);
>                   listar(frm.TProductos);*

**

> public void listar(JTable TProductos) {
>           modT = (DefaultTableModel) TProductos.getModel();
>           List lista = modDAO.listar();
>           Object[] object = new Object[5];
>
> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
>         object[0] = lista.get(i).getId();//arreglos
>         object[1] = lista.get(i).getNombre();
>         object[2] = lista.get(i).getCantidad();
>         object[3] = lista.get(i).getPrecio();
>         object[4] = lista.get(i).getCategoria();
>         modT.addRow(object);
>     }
>     frm.TProductos.setModel(modT);
> }
> ```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con leer? ¿A traducírtelos?

Comment: Más bien como a leer la línea de código de manera técnica, como por ejemplo "int número = 2; " se declara una avariable número de tipo entero igual a 2.